# Jquery Span click find next div

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I try to toogle div class from a span click i tried

```
$(this).closest(".div").find(".list-type-demandes").toggle();
```

but it doesn't work.

if i use :

```
$(".list-type-demandes").toggle();
```

it's works but it's showing me the two div and i need to display the div from "this" span

here HTML  :

```
<label style="color: #1c5081">
        <span id="toolbar-open" name="toolbar_open" class="toogle-toobar-open" onclick="toogleListTypeDemande(this)"><b>+</b>
        </span> Organisation, support et services
      </label>

      <div class="list-type-demandes" style="padding-left: ; display: none">
         <label style="display: inline">
         <input type="radio" class="checkbox_type_demande" data-appel-projet="474" name="appel_projet[type_demande_list]" value="54" id="appel_projet_type_demande_list_54"> Architecture d'entreprise
        </label>
      </div>

      <label style="color: #1c5081">
        <span id="toolbar-open" name="toolbar_open" class="toogle-toobar-open" onclick="toogleListTypeDemande(this)"><b>+</b></span> Applications
      </label>


      <div class="list-type-demandes" style="padding-left: ; display: none">
        <label style="display: inline">
        <input type="radio" class="checkbox_type_demande" data-appel-projet="474" name="appel_projet[type_demande_list]" value="52" id="appel_projet_type_demande_list_52"> Système d'information activités recherche
        </label>
      </div>
```

here the script :

```
function toogleListTypeDemande(element) {
        $(this).closest(".div").find(".list-type-demandes").toggle();
    }
```

Comment: What do you mean by `the div from "this" span`?

Comment: i mean i want to toggle the closest div from the span and not the two div when i use $(".list-type-demandes").toggle();

Comment: but if i click on span 1 and span 2 of course i would like to display the two div

Comment: your selector means you are looking for a class of div, not a div - remove the dot

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to modify `toogleListTypeDemande(element)` just a little.

Javascript offers the attribute **nextElementSibling** to get the next html element. Unfortunately there is no next sibling to your span element. So we need to travel one node back to get it's parent **element.parentNode** - which is the label - and from there the next sibling is the div.

```
function toogleListTypeDemande(element) {
        $(element.parentNode.nextElementSibling).toggle();
    }
```

Answer (score 1):

Use `ID` unique and check below code,

You can use directly click also

```
$('.toogle-toobar-open').click(function(){
  $(this).closest("label").next(".list-type-demandes").toggle();
});
```

```css
label{
  display:block;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.2.4/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script>
function toogleListTypeDemande(element) {
    $(element).closest("label").next(".list-type-demandes").toggle();
}
</script>
<label style="color: #1c5081">
        <span id="toolbar-open" name="toolbar_open" class="toogle-toobar-open" onclick="toogleListTypeDemande(this)"><b>+</b>Organisation, support et services
        </span> 
      </label>

      <div class="list-type-demandes" style="padding-left: ; display: none">
         <label style="display: inline">
         <input type="radio" class="checkbox_type_demande" data-appel-projet="474" name="appel_projet[type_demande_list]" value="54" id="appel_projet_type_demande_list_54"> Architecture d'entreprise
        </label>
      </div>

      <label style="color: #1c5081">
        <span id="toolbar-open2" name="toolbar_open" class="toogle-toobar-open" onclick="toogleListTypeDemande(this)"><b>+</b> Applications</span> 
      </label>


      <div class="list-type-demandes" style="padding-left: ; display: none">
        <label style="display: inline">
        <input type="radio" class="checkbox_type_demande" data-appel-projet="474" name="appel_projet[type_demande_list]" value="52" id="appel_projet_type_demande_list_52"> Système d'information activités recherche
        </label>
      </div>
```